# Rest api creation for multiple path variables

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I need to fetch names of all students who have enrolled for the courses.

Url:-/students/{course1}/{course2}
Eg /students/java/oracle

How to write controller, service and repository in rest api.

Entity:-
Student
Integer Id,String name and list coursenames

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/students")
public class StudentController {

  @Autowired
  private StudentService studentService;

  // /students/java,oracle
  @GetMapping(value="/{courses}")
  @ResponseBody
  public String getStudents(@PathVariable String[] courses) {
      return studentService.getStudents(courses);
  }

}
```

Student

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class StudentDao {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<CourseDao> course;
}
```

Course

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
public class CourseDao {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

In my opinion it is bad rest design. I'll create **POST** endpoint with body, which contains array with course Id's and find students by course id's.

Answer (score 0):

If the parameters are optional or an array you shouldn't use a path variable but use a request parameter.